# Sql Server int conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure InsertMovies
(
    @Title nvarchar(max),
    @Sdesc nvarchar(max),
    @LDesc nvarchar(max),
    @ImgUrl nvarchar(max),
    @TicketCost real, 
    @Seat int, 
    @StrDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime,
    @CineName nvarchar(max)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    Declare @temp int 
    SET @temp = Convert(int,'select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName') 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MovieSessions]
    (
        [Title],
        [ShortDescription],
        [LongDescription],
        [ImageUrl],
        [Price],
        [Seats], 
        [StartTime],
        [EndTime],
        [Cinemas_Id]
    ) 
    values
    (
        @Title,
        @Sdesc,
        @LDesc,
        @ImgUrl,
        @TicketCost,
        @Seat,
        @StrDate,
        @EndDate,
        @temp
    ) 
END 
GO
```

Please help me  properly cast the value from the select statement , I can create this procedure however I get an error on  execution , here is the error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertMovies, Line 6
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select Id from
>   [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName' to data type int.

Comment: you're converting a string to int instead of sql statement result.

Comment: Check if `Location` is also of datatype `varchar`

Comment: removing quotes will work, but only if this always return one result. Use `top 1` otherwise !

Answer (score 2):

This part is a problem for you ... your converting whole query text to int

```
SET @temp = Convert(int,'select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName')
```

Try it like this

```
SET @temp = (select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName)
```

Just to confirm, your ID field in Cinemas table is int type right?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes with brackets in query:

```
SET @temp = Convert(int,(select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting a particular `int`. Infact you are trying to convert the string `'select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName'` to `int` which is incorrect. Try to change:

```
SET @temp = Convert(int,(select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
SET @temp = (select Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] = @CineName)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your comment , you have been a great help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SET @temp = cast((select top 1 Id from [dbo].[Cinemas] where [Location] =
>   @CineName)as int)

use top 1 to avoid multiply result error

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
DECLARE @temp int 
SELECT @temp=cast(Id as INT) FROM [dbo].[Cinemas] WHERE[Location] = @CineName'
PRINT @TEMP
```